# How to get to if modifier's variables?

Tags: ruby, control-structure

Consider the following working code:

```
md = nil
begin
    puts md[:c]
    break
end if md = /(?<c>string)/.match('some string')
```

But it kind of looks ugly. Or not? I started with this one:

```
puts c if /(?<c>string)/ =~ 'some string'
```

But it didn't see `c` variable, so I put it this way:

```
puts md[:c] if md = /(?<c>string)/.match('some string')
```

And finally when I added `md = nil` it started working. How do you usually do this? Am I doing it wrong? What's happening here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the most straight forward way is also the best:

```
if md = /(?<c>string)/.match('some string')
  puts md[:c]
end
```

If you still want to use `if` modifier in a one-liner, you could use the [special global variables](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Special+global+variables) set after each match:

```
puts $~[:c] if /(?<c>string)/ =~ 'some string'
```

Or

```
puts $1 if /(string)/ =~ 'some string'
```

Comment: One might as well do it this way, then: `if /(?<c>string)/ =~ 'some string'; puts c; end` Is this still okay with you? Actually, it seems like there's no way to make it with if modifier, so you're suggesting using if statement syntax. You aren't possibly saying modifiers are useless?

Comment: @x-yuri - `if` modifiers are far from useless - they are great constructs. The problem is that `md` was not defined prior to this line, which means that the interpreter got confused. This way it is obvious for the interpreter (and the reader) when `md` is defined. Your suggestion using `c` is wrong, since you did not define variable `c` anywhere. You could use the variable automatically created during match - I'll post an update to the question with that option.

Answer (score 4):

Just pass a block to `Regexp#match` which will be processed only when MatchData object is returned:

```
/(?<c>string)/.match('some string') {|m| puts m[:c]}
```

Comment: Although, you suggested an interesting way to express it, could you elaborate on using if modifier syntax? You're suggesting your variant, because if modifier syntax is too wordy and outweighs the benefit of using if modifier syntax?

Comment: @x-yuri It's about style and personal preferences. There is nothing wrong with use *if* condition syntax instead, however find it less straightforward and it becomes more wordy when written in complete form, ie. with *else* part as a good practice from functional programming - expression should always return a value.

Comment: @x-yuri There is also advantage my version using block *won't pollute* objectspace, ie. `m` variable is local to a block and won't interferre with variable `m` from current namespace.